# Why is this function computable

Tags: computability

I'm struggling to understand why this function is computable.
This is the requirement:

Consider the following program P, written in a pseudo-C language:

```
P: 
{   
    int x, y, z; 
    read (x, y, z); 
    while (x != y) 
    { 
       x = x - y;  
       z = z + y;
    } 
    write z; 
}
```

Let $f(x, y, z)$ be the function computed by P. Is the following function g computable?

$g(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} 
  1 & f(x,y,z)\ halts \\
  0 & else 
   \end{cases} 
$

Whenever I encounter a problem like this, I try to imagine a program that does exactly what $g$ does. In this case, a `P2` program that checks if $f(x,y,z)$ halts.

Now, P halts if, basically, $x>y \ and \ y=1 $ or $x=y$ (there are probably more cases). In the other cases, P would just remain in the `while` loop, so $f$ is **not total**.

But how would `P2` return $0$ if P wouldn't even halt? P2 would have to wait, and never return 0, so for some values the function is not computable, and x,y,z isn't always computable.

What am I *thinking* wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that P halts iff $x = ty$ for some integer $t \geq 1$. Hence $g(x,y,z)$ is just the following function:
$$
g(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $x = ty$ for some integer $t \geq 1$}, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
Given integers $x,y$, it is not hard to check whether $x = ty$ for some integer $t \geq 1$. Hence $g$ is computable (even in polynomial time!).

Comment: But what about those values for when $x \neq ty$ ? P just loops, and never halts. How would $g$ know that?

Comment: My formula for $g$ doesn't mention P. As a related example, suppose that $c(n) = \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty 2^{-m}$. Then $c(n) = 2^{-n}$ is computable, despite the fact that $c$ cannot sum the infinite series and see what it gets.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to compute $g$ in a specific way. This is an obstacle that you're imposing on yourself for no reason. A function is just a mapping from input to output. Nothing more.

Comment: So the way of thinking when doing these problems is "there are some inputs, managed in some ways, for which $g$ is computable -> so it's computable"?

Comment: No, absolutely not. The way to think about is that $g$ is a function, not an algorithm. It has output $1$ if $x=ty$ for some integer $t \geq 1$, and it has output $0$ otherwise. How you implement $g$ is up to you. If you manage to find an algorithm that computes $g$, then it is computable.

Comment: I see. Thank you. One last thing: could you please show me an example of an uncomputable function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem.

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again, but my problem is very similar to the HP which is undecidable. I'm checking with a function $g$ if another $f$ halts or not on arbitrary inputs $x,y,z$. What is the difference?

Comment: You have a specific program $f$, for which the halting problem is computable. The halting problem for arbitrary programs is not computable. If you are still confused, I suggest asking a new question.